# single ajax Calendar extender for mutiple textbox and image controls?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I looking single ajax calendar extender for multiple text boxes and (calendar) image controls?

how can we do that? I found below good article on textboxes (not calendar images) controls.

Please help me to get this with image controls also

[link text](http://forums.asp.net/t/1088868.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function onlybackbutton(id) {                  

                  if (id == 1) {
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtCdatefrom.ClientID%>').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('<%=imgdatefrom.ClientID%>').click();
                  }
                  else if (id == 2) {
                        document.getElementById('<%=txtCdateTo.ClientID%>').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('<%=imgdateto.ClientID%>').click();
                  }
                  return false;
            }

      </script>



<table>
<tr>
                                          <td>
                                                Created Date From
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCdatefrom" runat="server" Width="180px" onpaste="return false;" onmousedown="return onlybackbutton(1);" onkeypress="return onlybackbutton(1);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgdatefrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/DatePicker.gif"
                                                      ImageAlign="Baseline" Height="16px" />
                                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calsearchdtfrm" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtCdatefrom"
                                                      Format="yyyy/MM/dd" PopupButtonID="imgdatefrom">
                                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                                Created Date To
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCdateTo" runat="server" Width="180px" onpaste="return false;" onmousedown="return onlybackbutton(2);" onkeypress="return onlybackbutton(2);"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgdateto" runat="server" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/images/DatePicker.gif" />
                                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtsearchdtto_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                                      TargetControlID="txtCdateTo" Format="yyyy/MM/dd" PopupButtonID="imgdateto">
                                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                          </td>
                                    </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obout has a pretty awesome library that includes an [AJAX Calendar](http://obout.com/calendar/calendar_home.aspx) control.